# Why is Java not supported in Azure Machine Learning Studio for Custom AI

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Why is Java not supported in Azure Machine Learning Studio for creating custom AI ML model, though Azure Cognitive Services support Java to access pre-trained models ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure ML Studio only supports Python and R because these are the common programming languages for data science, it's not set up to support Azure ML pipelines using java. However, you can use [existing models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-existing-model) created outside of Azure ML and [consume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-consume-web-service?tabs=python#call-the-service-java) models using Java. You can also [convert](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials) existing model from another format to ONNX and deploy in Azure ML.